# Generate Toast in async operations in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am getting a json response from a api , and now where the function that has called it , I want to generate a toast telling "your post can been created" but this this is a async operation it reverts backs an error

i was trying to simple generate a toast when my user create a post, whose response i am getting back

```
Future<http.Response> create(int deptid, String teachername, String section,
      String title, String content) {
    return http.post(Uri.parse(AppUrls.createpost),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
          'dept_id': deptid,
          'teacher_name': teachername,
          'section': section,
          'title': title,
          'content': content
        }));
  }
```

This is where i call it

```
InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                http.Response response = await create(int.parse(deptid.text),
                    teachername.text, section.text, title.text, content.text);
                Map<String, dynamic> obj = jsonDecode(response.body);

                // Text(obj['dept_id'].toString());
                // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously


                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
```

Here, i want to return a toast , but unable to do so

Answer (score 0):

**You could just add this package a flutter toast library import** https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast:

Here the code could help you achieve what you want:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await create(int.parse(deptid.text),
        teachername.text, section.text, title.text, content.text);
      Map<String, dynamic> obj = jsonDecode(response.body);

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Your post has been created",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
      );

      Navigator.pop(context);
    } catch (error) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Error creating post: $error",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: you have referenced it from a website , i had tried it but it didn't because we are doing it for a asynchronous operation